# Q: Dijkstra's algorithm C++ Finding shortest path from distances?

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra

After many hours of confusion with graphing and Dijkstra's algorithm I have found a reliable way to get the shortest distances for my use but, my question is since I know the shortest distance why can I not find the path it took to get the shortest path? It seems pretty simple and I think I am just overlooking where I would get the paths.

This currently works to find the distance:

```
float* Graphing::dijkstra(int src, int flag){
    float *dist;
    dist = new float[verticies+1];
    
    MinHeap *minh;
    minh = new MinHeap(verticies+1, flag);
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= verticies; i++){
        dist[i] = FLT_MAX;
        heapEntry temp;
        temp.weight = dist[i];
        temp.dest = i;
        minh->insertVal(temp);
    }
    dist[src] = 0;
    minh->decValAtIndex(src, dist[src]);
    while(minh->curSize>0){
        heapEntry minNode = minh->extractMin();
        
        int u = minNode.dest;
        
        AdjListNode *cur = graph->array[u].head;
        //Check adjacency list of minimum node;
        while(cur){
            int v = cur->dest;
            
            if(minh->isInMinHeap(v) && dist[u] != FLT_MAX && cur->weight + dist[u] < dist[v]){
                dist[v] = dist[u] + cur->weight;
                
                minh->decValAtIndex(v, dist[v]);
            }
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= verticies; i++){
        if(dist[i]!=FLT_MAX){
            cout << i << "\t" << dist[i] << endl;
        }else
            cout << i << "\tNone"<< endl;
    }
}
```

Everything works and is tested for being the shortest path weight, my question is how would I be able to get the path for each of the vertices?

*Edit:

I got it working,
What I did was make a new function that would get every possible path for one of the vertices (useful for my assignment) and take in the result of Dijkstra's algorithm compute each paths weights and compare with the results of Dijkstra. Maybe not the most efficient of solutions in terms of run time and space (everything) but its what works in my limited time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try typing *dijkstra path* in the search field at the top.

Comment: Just walk back from the destination. If destination is 20-distant, is there a neighbour with 19-distance? Yes. walk there. Then look look for a neighbour with 18-distance. O(n) walkback.

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks I will give that a try!